# Find the cross node for number of nodes in ArangoDB?

Tags: arangodb

I have a number of nodes connected through intermediate node of other type. Like on picture There are can be multiple middle nodes. I need to find all the middle nodes for a given number of nodes and sort it by number of links between my initial nodes. In my example given A, B, C, D it should return node E (4 links) folowing node F (3 links). Is this possible? If not may be it can be done using multiple requests? I was thinking about using SHORTEST_PATH function but seems it can only find path between nodes from the same collection?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very nice question, it challenged the AQL part of my brain ;)
Good news: it is totally possible with only one query utilizing `GRAPH_COMMON_NEIGHBORS` and a portion of math.
Common neighbors will count for how many of your selected vertices a cross is the connecting component (taking into account ordering A-E-B is different from B-E-A) using combinatorics we end up having `a*(a-1)=c` many combinations, where c is comupted. We use p/q formula to identify a (the number of connected vertices given in your set).

If the `type` of vertex is encoded in an attribute of the vertex object
the resulting AQL looks like this:

`FOR x in (
  (
  let nodes =  ["nodes/A","nodes/B","nodes/C","nodes/D"]
  for n in GRAPH_COMMON_NEIGHBORS("myGraph",nodes , nodes) 
    for f in VALUES(n)
      for s in VALUES(f)
        for candidate in s 
          filter candidate.type == "cross"
          collect crosses = candidate._key into counter
          return {crosses: crosses, connections: 0.5 + SQRT(0.25 + LENGTH(counter))}
  )
)
sort x.connections DESC
return x`

If you put the crosses in a different collection and filter by collection name the query will even get more efficient, we do not need to open any vertices that are not of type cross at all.

`FOR x in (
  (
  let nodes =  ["nodes/A","nodes/B","nodes/C","nodes/D"]
  for n in GRAPH_COMMON_NEIGHBORS("myGraph",nodes, nodes,
  {"vertexCollectionRestriction": "crosses"}, {"vertexCollectionRestriction": "crosses"}) 
    for f in VALUES(n)
      for s in VALUES(f)
        for candidate in s 
          collect crosses = candidate._key into counter
          return {crosses: crosses, connections: 0.5 + SQRT(0.25 + LENGTH(counter))}
  )
)
sort x.connections DESC
return x`

Both queries will yield the result on your dataset:

`[
  {
    "crosses": "E",
    "connections": 4
  },
  {
    "crosses": "F",
    "connections": 3
  }
]`

Comment: Wow, cool staph @mchacki Thank you a lot. Can you please explain me this part of it? filter candidate.type == "cross" is this 'type' an attribute of node or collection name? If attribute how your example can be rewritten to filter this "cross" by name of the collection?

Comment: You are welcome ;) in the Solution above `type`is an attribute of the vertex. If you put crosses in a different collection it makes the query even more efficient (no need to open all circle documents just to find out they are no crosses). I updated my post as comments do not allow nice formatting.